# WordPress Archive Posts Page no displaying properly

Tags: wordpress, archive, posts

The one page on my website is not displaying the posts properly. It is not showing in an orderly manner. I have tried to deactivate and activate plugins, republish the pages but it is still showing the same. Can anyone help where the problem may be?

[[image: Please see reference image attached1]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try customizing or resizing.

Or open every post and change it.

Are you want to show post like these? : [click here](https://mrunalmunot.wordpress.com/)

Comment: @Faye If worked mark as accepted and upvote it